# Could not instantiate mail function. Message was not sent PHPMailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send mails. I have deployed my website on Google Cloud VM Instance

Here is my mail sending code

```
<?php
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
            $mail = new \PHPMailer;
            //$mail->isSMTP();                           
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 
            $mail->Username = '';          
            $mail->Password = ''; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                
            $mail->Port = 587;                 
            $mail->isHTML(true); 
            $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
            $mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
            $mail->Body = "Hello, Below are the details of contact ";
            $mail->Body = "<table><tr><td>Name:</td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr><tr><td>Email Address:</td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr><tr><td>Subject :</td><td>".$_POST['subject']."</td></tr><tr><td> Message :</td>".$_POST['$POST['msg']."</td></tr></table>";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

But the mail is not be able to send. Can anyone help me out? I can provide further code references if anyone needs

Answer (score 1):

Try using SMTP to send email:

```php
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";

// optional
// used only when SMTP requires authentication

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'smtp_username';
$mail->Password = 'smtp_password';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out `isSMTP()` so you are not using SMTP (so none of your SMTP settings will do anything), but the default `mail()` transport. This requires that you have a mail server installed in your server, which you apparently don’t.

To fix, either install a mail server (postfix is good) or enable SMTP, as chirag suggested.

All of this is covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.